# (Gamer Question) Really Hard Word Problem About Balancing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Warriors have a fortress in which they need to defend against beasts. They gain points for defending. Warriors do 200dmg/sec to beasts who have health points of 200hp each. If a beast dies, they revive. The fortress that they need to defend is 1000hp (so basically, it's going to be used as warrior's hp). The number of beasts are 20. A beast does 30dmg/sec each hit to the fortress. Warriors get 3 points per 100dmg. Beasts don't need points meaning they just get 0 points or it just doesn't count. The question is, in a time period of 60 seconds, would warriors get more points from a beast with 10000hp than a beast with 200hp (its normal hp)? Or is it balanced?

EDIT*:

WarriorDmg=200dmg/sec                                                                                                                     Warrior(Fortress)Hp=1000hp                                                                                                                   PointsForWarrior=3points/100dmg                                                                                                        PointsForBeast=0points                                                                                                                           BeastDmg=30dmg/sec                                                                                                                             BeastHp=200hp                                                                                                                                       NumberOfBeasts=20

After a beast dies, they start attacking again. 
It takes an interval of 0.5 seconds before a dead beast starts attacking again.
If humans attack a beast with 200dmg/sec, and a beast's hp is 200. That means they die instantly. The beast is able to do at least 30 damage before they die. After 0.5, a beast revives again and it comes to a loop until the fortress is destroyed. (-1000hp from 30x)

QUESTION: In 60 seconds, would warriors get more POINTS defending beasts of 200hp, or get more points with beasts of 10000hp?

Assume that the group of warriors is the fortress itself. So once the fortress of 1000hp goes down, that's when warriors lose. Warrior damage applies to beast (200hp in normal circumstances). Beast damage applies to warriors (fortress of 1000hp)

Comment: Here are some questions that you haven't provided the answers to, which are (probably) essential to the question. You claim that warriors revive: under what mechanism can they die? Are there multiple beasts in the 200 scenario? The 10000 scenario? What are the beast(s) doing damage to? When beasts and warriors engage, which strikes first?

Comment: What else am I missing? I've retouched some variables.

Comment: Hm, I think that's enough. Let me think a bit.

Comment: One more thing, are there multiple warriors? Or is the 200/sec ouput their collective damage (i.e. the fortress' damage)?

Comment: Just think of warriors = fortress (one collective, one warrior). So warrior hp is 1000hp in which they do 200dmg/sec as their collective damage. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sanity check: the fortress survives in both scenarios. If it doesn't, then then the one that survives longer wins. This is because the effective hit point pool of beasts is infinite; the nominal hp doesn't matter because of the revival mechanism. Given that, for warriors accruing a constant number of points for a constant amount of damage, you have a direct relationship between survival time and points.

I will use dps for damage per second. Because beasts always do damage before death, we can model them as doing all of their damage at zero seconds and at the instant they revive, and model the warriors as attacking at the $.9$ second mark.

200hp scenario: Warriors kill one beast every second. Beasts revive every half second. Therefore, it does not matter how beasts are killed; all of them will deal $30$ damage, precisely once, at some time in each one-second interval. This deals $30*60=1800$ damage, which kills the warriors. So they do not survive.

10000hp scenario: No beast dies, $1800$ damage is still dealt.

Therefore, everything comes down to the warriors' final moments. There are certain scenarios in which it is possible for the 10000hp to be slightly more favorable to the warriors, but this difference is only relevant during this last second, so it cannot be more than 1 second worth of points. They die between second $33$ and $34$, so we are talking about a $3$% difference.

However, if it matters for multiplayer balancing reasons, it is probably relevant that it is *not* possible to adjust the parameters so the 200hp scenario has more favorable outcomes. This is because the difference between the two deals with the dying of the beasts, and so for example if the warriors attack at the .4 second mark instead of the .9 second mark, then killed beasts will ressurect before a full second has passed, and therefore receive two full attacks in a second.

Comment: For the 10,000hp scenario, do beasts do exactly 1800 damage as the 200hp scenario? Or do they do more?

Comment: Exactly the same. The fact that they have more hp does not change the fact that their damage output is still 30/sec; given 60 seconds to hit something, and the capacity to survive, $30\text{ dmg}/\text{sec}*60\text{ sec} = 1800$ dmg.